# Extracting processed information for a DNA sequence in PHP

Tags: php, perl, bioinformatics, information-extraction

Hi to the expert helpers,

This is my first question posted, and I see there are fabulous answers received for other questions. My question is below;

I want to extract results (output) given after processing my query related to DNA sequences (SNPs: Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms which has a specific unique ID to each SNP) by a website which provides the processing (e.g. FASTSNP website) on a ranking basis for the given SNP, and to be able to store the extracted results in a MySQL database. Is there a way to use regex or any other PHP and/or Perl (out command to do so? Can anyone who has done is please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be quite helpful to see some example input, and the data you would want to extract from that input. Is your problem writing a regex, or interfacing with a database? Do you already have some code? (It doesn't matter if it works, but It'll help us understand the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! First of all I would like to second @amon. If you have any kind of code ideas, please post them. Otherwise, you shoudl maybe formulate a more precise question. That said, I'll try to give an answer anyway and could update it if you provide any further specifications.

If you are working with sequences or even more generally speaking, bioinformatics, you should definitely have a look at [Bioperl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page). It comes with interfaces for most commonly used data formats in bioinformatics and even with interfaces to certain online ressources, including databases.
And then there are Perl modules to interface with databases in general, for SQL databases I would guess that [SQL::DB](https://metacpan.org/module/MLAWREN/SQL-DB-0.971.0/lib/SQL/DB.pod) is probably a good starting point, but haven't used any of that myself, so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would humbly recommend that you use perl.

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) can run the query for you and get the results. It has a submit_form method. The simple example ( the synopsis ) on the linked page shows you how.

Once you have the results, you can use [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) to order the results just about any way you need to.

There are also lots of great modules for database access.

Can you post an example query you might send to the FASTSNP site?